# Error System.TypeLoadException en Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.forms, geolocalización

estoy empezando a programar aplicaciones móviles cross platform, estoy desarrollando en visual studio 2017, en el proyecto en el que trabajo me veo en la necesidad de usar geolocalización, para ello instale "Xamarin.Forms.Maps", lo hice de la siguiente manera:

-Dependencias
-Administrar Paquetes de Nugets
-Examinar
-(Busque e instale el SDK)

El proyecto compila, pero al momento de querer ejecutar el modo "Debug" en mi dispositivo Android, me tira este error:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000005
> from typeref (expected class 'ResourceLoadingQuery' in assembly '')

De manera mas especifica, el error me lo marca en el archivo "App.xaml.cs" en la linea que ejecuta "InitializeComponent();"

Anteriormente ya me había pasado algo similar al instalar "Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" y basto solo con limpiar y recompilar la solución, pero esta vez no se que mas puede ser, que lio esto de agregar SDK al proyecto, espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: En el xaml tienes definido este componente de map? si es asi, intentaste quitarlo a ver si ejecuta sin problema. Al menos para validar que sea ese componente el que cause el error.

Comment: No, lo tengo definido en otro form llamado Cuenta.xaml, pero intentare quitándolo y te comento que resulto de ello, muchas Gracias Leandro.

Comment: Sobre este detalle, tuve que generar un proyecto nuevo, ya que por alguna razón el SDK lo "rompió"; resulta extraño, pues lo instale después de haber leído documentación de Microsoft en el que hacían uso de el, en fin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analizando la documentacion, se requiere de una key

[Get a Google Maps API key](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup#get-a-google-maps-api-key)

para configurar el componente, la cual deebs configurar en el `AndroidManifest.xml`

[Google Maps fácil en Xamarin Forms](https://xamarinlatino.com/google-maps-f%C3%A1cil-en-xamarin-forms-7b84d474b3f1)

valida que tengas la linea

```
<meta-data android:name=“com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY” android:value=“PASTE-YOUR-API-KEY-HERE” />
```

Igualmente veo que este mensaje tambien suele referirse a problemas con los componentes con lo cual recomiendan eliminar el contenido de las carpetas `\bin` y `\obj` y volver a compilar. Quizas debas cerrar y volver abrir el Visual Studio.

Comment: Genial, intentare también esto :)

Comment: Leandro, tu recomendación me ayudo a solucionar el problema con el acceso a coordenadas, no se como agradecerte :)